# Crystal Reports “the ) is missing”

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to run a report that has already been created and works. But when I try to run an error pops up with the 'Formula Workshop' screen and it says "the ) is missing". This is the formula displayed:

```
if({a.sched_firm_qty}+{a.sched_excess_qty} != 0)
then
(({a.actual_firm_qty}+{a.actual_excess_qty}) / ({a.sched_firm_qty}+{a.sched_excess_qty}))-1
else
-1
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula should look like

```
if(({a.sched_firm_qty}+{a.sched_excess_qty}) <> 0)
then
(({a.actual_firm_qty}+{a.actual_excess_qty}) / ({a.sched_firm_qty}+{a.sched_excess_qty}))-1
else
-1
```

I've added one additional bracket for first summary and replaced matching operator. `<>` is equivalent for `!=` in CR. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much..  i was stuck on this since so long. thank you so so much. Upvoted

Comment: Just did! Thanks :)